# How to delete those columns of a file in which there is less than 2 digits?

Tags: linux

I have a file looks like:

input:

```
112 1 2 01 1 
000 0 0 22 0
122 2 2 22 0
```

I want to delete those columns in which there is less than 2 digits in each row. So the out should look like:

```
112 01
000 22
122 22
```

any suggestion? note that the real file is huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way, with perl:

```
perl -alne 'print join " ", grep { length > 1 } @F' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with sed (or more capable tools such as awk or perl).

For example

```
  sed -e :loop \
        -e 's/^[0-9]\{1\} //' \
        -e 's/ [0-9]\{1\}$//' \
        -e 's/ [0-9]\{1\} / /g' \
        -e 't loop' <input >output
```